# Change the location address without causing state loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, single-page-application, angular-ui-router

I am using AngularJS 1.2+ and Angular UI Router.
I am trying to change the location address without causing a reload. I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
function setPath(stateName, stateParams) {
    var path = $delegate.href(stateName, stateParams);
    var off = $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        off();
    });
    $location.path(path).replace();
}
setPath('my.state.name', myStateParams);
```

After calling that, the location didn't changed.
Is it possible anyway? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Not sure if this doesn't work with UI Router but lots of suggestions here around the skipReload function:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1699

Comment: @ArthurFrankel I've tried some similar ways. It doesn't work. I don't know which event to listen.

Comment: I would assume the $locationChangeSuccess event?